# Symfony - How to add ORM index to the Trait

Tags: symfony, indexing, doctrine-orm, traits

I have several entities (lets say 5), which use this trait, and I want to add an index to uuid field via the trait, 
so I want just use the trait in some specific entity and as a result have an indexed field in the entity

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS;
trait UuidTrait {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true, options={"default": null})
     */
    protected $uuid;

    public function getUuid()
    {
        //common code
    }

    public function generateUuid()
    {
        //common code
    }

    public function setUuid($uuid)
    {
        //common code
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct annotation supported to add an index directly at the column definition.
And a trait is pretty much a plain include of a file.

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#column

There is also a case open on github

https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/6249

There is a workaround that could work, but it might not fit your model requirements. 
You can define the column as unique, which will create an index.
But you will have to make the column non-nullable.

That said, from an optimization point of view, such a setting belongs at the table level, where it will be easier to have an overview of your existing indexes and judge if you have to fine-tune one or more of them.